# Is it a wise practice to have fetch requests inside a ComponentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

Hey my current react project is some kind of a product searching platform where users type in their criteria in a form > get shown their search results > compare some of the results if they want to. Each of these three actions happen on a page of their own.

Implementation:

Form's `key:value` pairs are transformed into a querystring which is dynamically inserted into a `<Link/>` component which directs to the results page.

When the `<Link/>` is clicked, results page are opened and the previous query string is inserted into the fetch in its `ComponentDidMount()` method.

Then the same query transfer process happens if you want to go from the results page to the comparison page.

The thing is whenever I go back from the comparison to results page, the fetch reoccurs instead of just loading a previously loaded page. Is this a good practice? And what about the way i send query between pages? is that ideal? If say i must transfer more info between pages, would it still be ideal to include all those data in a querystring between pages? Or is there other methods?

Comment: If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: it's wiser to revisit your query patterns and decide if you will support optimistic responses.

Answer (score 0):

What I use is a method for the fetch, and inside the `ComponentDidMount` I only call the method, in that way I don't write two times the fetch and can handle it outside the mount.